# What is the return value of "times" system call in linux

Tags: c, api, gcc, time, clock

I am having a legacy function(which is given below) to find the tick count, that means how much time the system is up.

```
    long findtick()
    {
        struct tms buf;
        clock_t tickcount = 0;
        tickcount = times(&buf);
        return (long)tickcount; 
    }
```

I am not able to find the behaviour of `times` system call and `clock_t` structure type.

My doubts are

1. What is the behaviour and return value of `times` system call in linux.
2. What is the structure definition of `clock_t`
3. Will this function return tickcount in seconds?
4. By any chance can this function return -1, because its return type is `signed long`

I am using `gcc` compiler in suse 10.

Comment: Seems to me that you don't know `man` command. Try `man times`.

Comment: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/times.2.html

Comment: man is not giving details about times api

Comment: oh i just tired man times. man 2 times is giving details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What is the behaviour and return value of times system call in linux.

   Ans : [times](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/times.2.html)
2. What is the structure definition of clock_t

   Ans : `typedef clock_t long` which is defined in ctime.h
3. Will this function return tickcount in seconds?

   Ans : yes
4. By any chance can this function return `-1`, because its return type is signed long

   Ans : In failure case, `times` will return `-1`

Thanks @cnicutar